# Pickle load: ImportError: No module named doc2vec_ext

Tags: python, pickle, gensim

This is the structure I'm dealing with:

```
src/
    processing/
        station_level/
            train_paragraph_vectors.py
    doc2vec_ext.py
    word_embeddings_station_level.py
```

I have trained and stored a model in `word_embeddings_station_level.py` like this:

```
from src.doc2vec_ext import WeightedDoc2Vec

# ...

model = WeightedDoc2Vec(
    # ...
)

train(model, vocab, station_sentences, num_epochs)

# Saving the model -> pickles it
model.save(open(model_file, "w"))
```

This is working fine so far. However, I want to load that model in `train_paragraph_vectors.py` like this:

```
import sys
from src import doc2vec_ext
sys.modules["doc2vec_ext"] = doc2vec_ext

if __name__ == "__main__":
# ...
    model = doc2vec_ext.WeightedDoc2Vec.load(station_level_sentence_vectors)
```

but I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/python/kaggle/seizure_prediction/src/processing/station_level/train_paragraph_vectors.py", line 57, in <module>
    model = doc2vec_ext.WeightedDoc2Vec.load(station_level_sentence_vectors)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 1684, in load
    model = super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 248, in load
    obj = unpickle(fname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 911, in unpickle
    return _pickle.loads(f.read())
ImportError: No module named doc2vec_ext
```

**doc2vec_ext.py**

Here you can see, that I just inherit from the `gensim.models.Doc2Vec` class and do some stuff:

```
class WeightedDoc2Vec(Doc2Vec):

    def __init__(self, dm=1,window=5, f_size=0, size=100, min_count=1, negative=0, dbow_words=1, alpha=0.015, workers=8, seed=42, dm_weighted=False, dm_stacked=False):
        Doc2Vec.__init__(self,
            # Constructor arguments ..
            )

        # ...
```

I don't know what's the problem here. I've tried to do the `sys.modules[]` but it's still not working properly.

How can I load my stored model?

---

**Important:**

I noticed that I can't even load from the same module. If I try to load the model in the file where it was created (here `word_embeddings_station_level.py`) it's still not working giving me the same error.

Comment: Is there a chance you are using two different python environments? Or maybe you are running the scripts from different locations so it is finding some modules in the current directory, but not finding them when you are out of that directory. These are just guesses.

Comment: Also do you have `__init__.py` files in your directory structure for each directory. If not, the package may not be loading modules properly.

Comment: @daveydave400 Well to make sure I don't mess too much up I added a line to load the model in the same script that is creating it. I'm sure I use the same Python interpreter and I now made sure that I run it from the same location. :/

Comment: @daveydave400 Each directory has a `__init__.py` file - but do I have to keep something in mind there?

Answer (score 0):

When saving and loading binary data like a pickle, you need to use binary mode, not text mode.

```
model.save(open(model_file, "wb"))  # 'b' for binary
```