# Can't pickle <class 'MemoryError'>: it's not the same object as builtins.MemoryError

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, docker-container

I am using multiproccessing pool map in Python 3.7 and I am getting error like below with Docker container.

```
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncoding Error: Error sending result: '<multiprocessing.pool.ExceptionWithTraceback object at 0x7f8ff58e8110>'. Reason: 'PicklingError("Can't pickle <class 'MemoryError'>: it's not the same object as builtins.MemoryError")'
```

I am using code like below:

```
def foo(track):
   
    track_url = track[1]
    url = requests.get(track_url)
    hashes = fingerprint.fingerprint_worker(
        BytesIO(url.content)
    )
    return True
    
def worker:
 tracks = [[1, "track_url_1"], [2, "track_url_2"]]

 with multiprocessing.Pool(const.MULTIPROCESSING_POOL_SIZE) as pool:
                pool.map(foo, tracks)
                pool.close()
                pool.terminate()
                pool.join()
```

MULTIPROCESSING_POOL_SIZE = 1

Complete stack trace of this error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
 return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
 response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
 raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
 response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
 rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise 
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/radio-streaming-fingerprint/app.py", line 37, in fingerprint_covers_tracks
resp = fp.fingerprint_tracks(track, generate_fingerprints_with_pool)
File "/radio-streaming-fingerprint/fingerprint.py", line 37, in fingerprint_tracks
pool.map(generate_fingerprints_with_pool, tracks)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in map
return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
raise self._value
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '<multiprocessing.pool.ExceptionWithTraceback object at 0x7f8ff58e8110>'. Reason: 'PicklingError("Can't pickle <class 'MemoryError'>: it's not the same object as builtins.MemoryError")'
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error in my production environment, but not in my local project setup, there is 4GB RAM in my Docker container.

Comment: How much disk space did you allocated for your docker?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121874/python-pickling-after-changing-a-modules-directory/70504686#70504686

Answer (score 0):

In multiprocessing pool, the resources cannot be shared. Because it runs in isolated cores. It seems that the "fingerprint_worker" is a shared method between processes.
Use multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool instead:

```
with multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(const.MULTIPROCESSING_POOL_SIZE) as pool:
    pool.map(foo, tracks)
```