# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.saving'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Complete Error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 32, in <module>
    pickled_model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.saving'
```

I am not able to solve this error.
Thanks for the help:)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please see this answer, which talks about the constraints around using pickle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121874/python-pickling-after-changing-a-modules-directory

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error while compiling the following code

```
import tensorflow
import pickle
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_option_menu import option_menu
from tensorflow import keras

pickle_in = open("C:/Users/zahir/Desktop/Heart_Disease_prediction/Saved_model/classifier.pkl", 'rb')
tb_model = pickle.load(pickle_in)
```

I saved model using pickle library and trying to open.

Comment: I run the same code in colab and when I tried to open the model file got that erro

Comment: failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this problem with Keras 2.3 and TensorFlow 2.5. After I upgrade to Keras 2.9 and TensorFlow 2.9, the problem was solved.