# Pickling a complex dictionary/ Making the dictionary portable

Tags: python, pickle, joblib, dill

I have a dictionary in which I collect ML models, that I built with a dataclass as follows:

```py
  @dataclass(frozen=True, order=True)
    class Model:
        data_sample: str
        predictive_model: object
        predictions: pd.DataFrame
        binary: object
        type: str
        inputs: list
        output: str
        explain: bool

        def to_dict(self):
            return asdict(self)
```

I produce multiple models and use the dataclass to validate the inputs for a single, trained model. I cast this class as a dictionary to an ML list:

```py
ML.append(model.to_dict())
```

The objects for `binary` and `predictive_model` are models (python classes) that come from libraries like scikit-learn, TPOT, SciPy and so on. One should assume that there is a lot of inheritance happening in these objects. I am struggling to make this list portable to another environment. My core idea of making this portable is to use libs like `joblib`, `dill` or `pickle` to `.dump` the dictionary in the runtime that trains the models, and use a `.load` method to load the dictionary. When I do this, I notice that there is a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ...` error. I already found this to be a common problem, and that there are answers around this error here: [Python pickling after changing a module's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121874/python-pickling-after-changing-a-modules-directory)

My question is: Is there a better way to "export" my dictionary? Preferably in such a way that it copies everything that it needs so that I can run this elsewhere without needing to manage any imports?

I get the feeling that pickling might not be what I need..

Comment: Can you provide example on how you are deserializing the models? Are you importing the necessary sci libraries in the same file that you are deserializing?