# How to I change import statements in a pickle file?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I recently removed a module `xyz` and replace it with another one of a different name `abc`. In some pickle files, it still imports the `xyz` module. I want to change it to import the `abc` module. How can I do this?

I don't have much experience with serialization/deserialization. My understanding is I'd have to read in the pickle file (i.e., deserialize) and somehow make the changes and then serialize it again after the changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pickling after changing a module's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121874/python-pickling-after-changing-a-modules-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying the pickle file, you can "synthetically" import `abc` as `xyz` by manually updating [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules):

```
import sys

import abc

sys.modules["xyz"] = abc
```

Any attempts to import `xyz` will use the already loaded `xyz` module, which is just an alias of `abc`.

```
import xyz

>>> print(xyz)
<module 'abc' ...>
```

After inserting the relevant modules into `sys.modules`, you will be able to load the old pickle file without any modifications to the file itself.

Since the deserialized objects will have been loaded using the members of `abc`, if you immediately re-pickle them, you'll get a pickle file that only contains references to `abc` (and not `xyz`).

Comment: I want to remove any trace of mentioning to `abc` though. This will only just add more "mentions" of a deprecated module that has been removed

Comment: @roulette01 I'm not sure I understand - you want to remove mentions to both `xyz` (the old module) and `abc` (the new module)? The approach replaces mentions of `xyz` with `abc`

Comment: Sorry, I meant I want to remove any trace of mentioning `xyz`

Comment: @roulette01 If you follow these steps, there won't be any trace of `xyz` left. `xyz.Foo` in the original pickle file will become `abc.Foo`

Comment: ahh I think I misread. Let me try it

Comment: I think this method will work but having a hard time validating it on my particular pickle file (I don't actually know what all the contents in it entail).

I followed your suggestion, and then loaded the file using `with open(path, 'rb') as file: data = pickle.load(file)` and then immediately `with open(path, 'wb') as file: pickle.dump(data, file)` but then I get an error 
`copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle Cursor objects
`

Comment: @roulette01 That looks like an unrelated issue due to an unpicklable object being added as an attribute for some class. Did you make a change like that when you moved `xyz` to `abc`?

Comment: hmm I may have, but idk why there would be a cursor (i think it's referring to a sqlite3 cursor but not certain) in the serialized data in the first place. or maybe I don't understand how the serialization is working in this case. is it trying to serialize the entire `abc` module?

Comment: Based on that error, the serialized data does not contain a `Cursor`. However, re-constructing the serialized objects using the definitions in the new `abc` modules results in a `Cursor` instance being saved somewhere as an attribute. That `Cursor` object isn't serializable, so pickling the new objects fails

Comment: accepted this answer since it answers the underlying question. i'll try to debug my issue some more. from what I can see, both `abc, xyz` have a cursor object, so it's not clear how it was serialized in the first place (my guess is maybe it was serialized prior to `abc` introducing the cursor and it was never re-seralized afterwords). This pickle file is used for unit testing and hasn't been touched in ages

Comment: Pickle does not serialize modules. The pickle format essentially consists of paths to types (which get imported at unpickle time) and tuples of basic data which a class can use to "reconstruct itself".

Comment: Is this approach compatible with `dill` package? I needed to use `dill` to get around the cursor issue. After I re-serialized the file and tried to reload, I still get the same issue with it trying to load from `xyz`