# How to locate object that cannot be pickled inside complex object

Tags: python, serialization, cursor, pickle

Related to my earlier question: [How to I change import statements in a pickle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77341161/how-to-i-change-import-statements-in-a-pickle-file)

I am trying to change an import statement inside a serialized file. It ended up causing some unexpected issues when trying to re-serialize, in particular:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    CP.dump(data, file)
  File "/path/to/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle Cursor objects
```

(Yes, unfortunately, I'm constrained to py2 here)

The serialized object is a class instance. I removed the cursor that I thought was causing this error, but after removing it, I still observe this error, so that tells me there's another cursor elsewhere. The problem is this class instance is quite large and is composed of numerous other class instances recursively. I don't want to dig through all of them to find the cursor, so I was wondering if there's a quick way to determine where the cursor is coming from?

Also, it doesn't say what kind of Cursor it is, but I think it's probably a sqlite3 cursor.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569754/)?

Comment: @Selcuk ah no I have not, I think the first answer may be helpful. I was actually trying to print some stuff from `copy_reg.py` earlier, but it's installed in some directory where I don't have write access so I've been waiting for access to be granted

Comment: @Selcuk Just got edit permissions, and I added the suggested print statement from the above answer `print self # new`, but this wasn't very helpful. It prints `<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f02acd473b0>` which I already suspected but doesn't tell me which class this object belongs to

Comment: You could have also monkey-patched the `_reduce_ex` method at runtime, without actually needing to modify the `.py` file. I don't have Python 2 anymore, so I can help further, sorry.